# Breakdown voltage of a back-to-back MOSFET configuration (aka "Bidirectional Power Switch")

Tags: mosfet, breakdown

In a back-to-back MOSFET configuration, if the single MOSFET is maximum-rated at BVDSS=100 V (like the IRF530 in the example), does that mean that the series of both has a breakdown voltage of 200 V or rather 100 V?

My argument in favor of 100 V would be that the lower MOSFET's forward-biased body diode has a maximum voltage of 0.4-0.8V if current starts to flow, so only the upper MOSFET is truly blocking. But I am not sure if this is the correct way of looking at it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp557x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes: the total breakdown voltage is the sum of (Reverse-Bias) + (Forward Bias).  So 100V + 0.6V.

Comment: Think about it this way: if M1 were to conduct, then that puts 150V on the gate of M2, which will definitely cause M2 to fail (source-gate voltage limit is typically +/-20V or less.)

Comment: Your schematic has the gates shorted to the sources. This short should be replaced with a gate driving circuit.

Comment: The shorted gates are only for artificially forcing the MOSFET into off-state (i.e. only for demonstration).